# Data lake to CosmosDB sync - one directional

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage

We have daily aggregated data (using USQL script) in Azure Data lake which we are planning to copy to CosmosDB using Azure data factory, so that we can use it as reporting back end. I want to sync data from data lake with CosmosDB (one direction from lake to CosmosDB). If any file get updated or deleted in lake, cosmosDB should be updated accordingly.

I have one thought for this - In USQL script we can have one more output to BlobStorage with only run details (without actual data) - just to take advantage of BlobTrigger, so that for each new blob created, it will automatically call Azure Function. Azure function will run respective slice of ADF job to copy data from lake to CosmosDB.

Update scenario - 
When we do re-aggregation of old date (whose data is already ingested in CosmosDB), new blob will get created in blob storage, but this time Azure function will run different activity - custom activity of ADF which will delete all existing records from CosmosDB and ingest new records.  But there is one issue. New records may be different from old ingested records, so we need to maintain primary key of all records for each run. To resolve this issue, we can keep primary key (partition key + id in CosmosDB) in another separate output in data lake using same USQL script. This output will be read from ADF custom activity to delete existing records from CosmosDB.

Please let know your thoughts on above approach. Am I thinking correctly or not? Is there any better approach/Azure service which I can use here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that it is a good way to use blob trigger to do that.

Comment: In your update scenario you can use DocumentClient.UpsertDocumentAsync method instead of deletion and inserting afterwards